# uWSGI python subprocess chrome/firefox failed

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have a python flask app under uWSGI served using nginx.
The python code calls `subprocess.Popen()` to run a browser (i.e. Firefox, Chrome) but the uWSGI log shows errors.
The error is related to linux(ubuntu) standard commands i.e. `readlink`, `which`, `cat` and others.

I am suspecting this is user access related, but not sure.
The uWSGI service runs using my user and `www-data` group.

**Python Code**

```
import subprocess

@app.route('/api/check/version', methods=['POST'])
def check_version():
    pid = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/firefox', '--version'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    #pid = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/google-chrome', '--version'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    data = pid.communicate()
    return  data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_version()
```

**uWSGI log**

```
**in case of doing Popen for /usr/bin/firefox
/usr/bin/firefox: 1: /usr/bin/firefox: which: not found

**in case of doing Popen for /usr/bin/google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable: line 8: readlink: command not found
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable: line 10: dirname: command not found
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable: line 46: exec: cat: not found
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable: line 45: exec: cat: not found
```

**uWSGI Service Config**

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myuser
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/gbadmin/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/gbadmin/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/gbadmin/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're giving your `PATH` a much-too-restrictive value:

```
Environment="PATH=/home/gbadmin/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
```

The missing commands in question are usually present in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, adding these to the path variable will likely solve your problem

```
Environment="PATH=/home/gbadmin/myproject/myprojectenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick clear reply, this solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not answering your question but I guess I'm solving the problem you are encountering. As an alternative you could `dpkg -s firefox | grep '^Version:'` instead of the method you are using.

Comment: Thanks Juggernaut, the version is only a sample of required action. There are more commands require Popen but I provided a sample scenario only.